# How to get the root of project which installed my npm module?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am developing an NPM package. Now I want to know the easiest way to get the root of the project which utilizes my custom package.

Within my package itself it is pretty easy to get the root in node.js like so:

```
__dirname
```

This points to the root of my package itself though. I would like to get the root of the project which actually performed the `npm install` of my package though.

Obviously, I could simply go up from the `node_modules` directory and assume that the root directory is there but this sounds really bad.

Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the info from: [require.main](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main)

> The Module object representing the entry script loaded when the
>   Node.js process launched. See "Accessing the main module".

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.dirname(require.main.filename));
```

Having this folder structure:

```
/app
  entry.js
  node_modules/
    my-package/
      index.js
```

**app/entry.js**

```
const myPackage = require('my-package');
```

**app/node_modules/my-package/index.js**

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.dirname(require.main.filename));
```

And when you call: `node entry.js`

You will get: `/app` printed to stdout.

Comment: This leaves me with the root of the package itself, not the root of the project which uses my package.

Comment: How are you running node? are you calling your package directly?

Comment: It it being called as an executable through npm scripts in my main project. In my custom package I have set up a `bin` property in the `package.json`.

Comment: Just added: `path.dirname(require.main.filename)` to any package I have in `node_modules` and it's printing my project root.

Comment: There is no way it isn't working, you're doing something wrong, `require.main.filename` contains the entry point, unless your entry point isn't in the root of your project, you have something else going on. Post your directory structure and where is your entry point.

Comment: It fails because I used `npm link` which create a symlink for local development of my package. I am unsure on how to handle this though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171837/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-stephan-v).

Comment: for some reason this gives me the bin folder in node_modules when running tests

Answer (score 3):

you could use [app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path) which is an npm module and its pretty neat.

`npm i -S app-root-path`

after that just do

```
var reqlib = require('app-root-path').require;
var myModule = reqlib('/lib/my-module.js');
```

Comment: @Stephan-v it works like you thought , just by  finding the root `node_modules`  directory.

Answer (score 2):

KISS

```
const fullPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
const regexResp = /^(.*?)node_modules/.exec(fullPath);
const appRoot = regexResp ? regexResp[1] : fullPath;
console.log(appRoot); // outputs the directory which is the root of this project
```